# Windows batch file to copy file with its great-grandparent directory added as prefix to filename

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a file/directory structure like this:

```
C:\Results\name1\run\string1\output.csv
C:\Results\name2\run\string2\output.csv
C:\Results\name3\run\string3\output.csv
...
```

I'd like to copy each `output.csv` to `C:\Results` with its great-grandparent directory name added as a prefix to the file, so I have this:

```
C:\Results\name1output.csv
C:\Results\name2output.csv
C:\Results\name3output.csv
```

I'm trying to use the batch code as posted below, but it's not quite there.
(I tried to cobble this together from other online searches.)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /A:D /S /B "C:\Results*"') do (
    for %%y in ("%%a\*.csv") do (
        call :GETPARENTPARENT "%%y" ret

        echo ret=!ret!
        move /Y "%%y" "!ret!"
        pause
    )
)

goto :EOF

:GETPARENTPARENT
set fileP=%1
echo received=%fileP%
for %%a in (%fileP%) do (
    set parent=%%~dpa
    cd !parent!\..\..
    for /r %%a in (*.csv) do for %%b in ("%%~dpa\.")

    do ren "%%~a" "%%~nxb%%~xa"
    set gparent=%%~dpa
    cd !gparent!\..
    set PPPath=!cd!
    for %%x in ("!PPPath!") do (
        set "%~2=%%~dpnx"
    )
)
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Cmd.exe shell scripts (batch files) have nothing whatsoever to do with DOS.

Comment: What do you mean by "not quite there" ? Does your code crash? (It should since `do` must be on the same physical line as `for`) or simply not work as expected (which may have to do with your attempt to nest two `for` statements using the *same* metavariable, `%%a`)

Comment: [DOS and cmd are different](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). You shouldn't tag DOS unless when the script is supposed to run under DOS

Comment: You already have the Great Grandparent in your first `FOR` command.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work (remove 'echo' when you're sure):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set baseFolder=C:\Results

cd /D %baseFolder%

for /D %%D in (*) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir /S /B "*.csv"') do (
        set "filename=%%~nxA"
        for /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%G in ("%%A") do set "newname=%baseFolder%\%%G!filename!"

        echo move /Y "%%A" "!newname!"
        pause
    )
)
```

But if there are multiple sub folders, it would be better to add more to the file names so they are unique:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set baseFolder=C:\Results

cd /D %baseFolder%

for /D %%D in (*) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir /S /B "*.csv"') do (
        set "filename=%%~nxA"
        for /f "tokens=3,4,5 delims=\" %%G in ("%%A") do set "newname=%baseFolder%\%%G%%H%%I!filename!"

        echo move /Y "%%A" "!newname!"
        pause
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to find just `*.csv` file and `copy` (but your script use `move`, if so, just replace the above `copy` to `move`.

1 command line and **just search disk once**:

`msr -l -rp C:\Results -f "\.csv$" -PAC | msr -it "(.*?Results\\[^\\]+).*?([^\\]+)$" -o "copy $0 $1$2" -X`

The above command line: Find the `*.csv` files recursively, then generate copy command lines and execute (`-X`)

- Remove `-X` if you just want to **preview command lines**.
- Add `-PAC`(like `-X -PAC` or `-XPAC` or `-P -A -C -X` etc.)  to hide other info.

`msr.exe` is a single exe (about 1.6MB, no dependency) for file/pipe/text processing (search/replace) in my open project https://github.com/qualiu/msr `tools` directory, with cross-platform versions. Docs like built-in usage: https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/msr-Windows.html